# Maven Multi Module Project + root pom plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, multi-module

I have a maven multi module project why is it when I put this configuration:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
 <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.3</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
  <phase>process-resources</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>generate</goal>
  </goals>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

in the root pom and mvn install the project no rebel.xml file is generated.
I can generate it using mvn org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.3:generate but that only creates the rebel.xml under target/classes and does not include it in the jar\war package.

But when I put the above configuration in the individual maven module it does generate it during install and includes it in the package as per process-resources

But I don't want to duplicate the plugin in all modules, but only put it in the root pom and during install is should generate the rebel.xml file and include in the package.

Am I missing how maven works?

Comment: Did you put that in the [Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) section or in the [pluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) section? Does the parent pom has its packaging element set to pom?

Comment: Thanks Augusto, I put it in the plugins section only, sounds like I need to put it in the pluginManagement section, will try that. And yes the root is pom package.

Comment: It should be fine if it's in the plugins section :S.

Comment: ya, adding to pluginManagement does not seem to help, will put back into plugins section

Comment: Turns out it was my bad I had put the plugin by error in the pluginManagement section when I thought I had put it in the build>plugins section where it should be, now it's working fine. Many Thanks

Comment: Thanks, similar thing happened to me, and fixed by moving it from pluginsManagement to plugins.

Comment: I don't know what the protocol here is for this kind of question/answer. I think it is useful to have questions like this where the answer is, essentially, oops. If you did it, chances are (and evidence here supports) that others will do this. So I would think it is a good idea to answer your own question, rather than just leaving it here in the comments. Answering your own questions is fine, as per the faq and this blog entry: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was my bad I had put the plugin by error in the pluginManagement section when I thought I had put it in the build>plugins section where it should be, now it's working fine. Many Thanks

Comment: I made the same mistake, and now I have the jrebel plugin under `<build><plugins>` tag, and I can use `mvn jrebel:generate` command, but in my project I have some jar modules, and in theses jar modules the rebel.xml must be in the root, not in target/classes, and the command above doesn´t create them in the root, any idea?